# Class A most significant bits '0' as in RFC1166 or older or '00' as suggested in RFC4632?

Tags: ipv4, internet, ip-address, rfc

I was just reading RFC4632 ["2. History and Problem Description"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632#page-3) and I don't get the part about Class A with MSB '00'. That would in my understanding mean, there are actually only 64 available networks, which collides with my knowledge, that there are more /8 networks actually. The RFC also suggest, there are 128 possible networks in Class A, which would mean, there is only one MSB '0' e.g.
From what I read in older RFCs, such as [RFC1166 section Network Numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1166#page-4), there is only MSB '0' in Class A.

So what have I missed? In case, the RFC would be incorrect, whom should I contact to correct it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be a typo in that RFC. Notice that the header of the RFC says `Errata Exist`. It is not uncommon for things like that to happen.

That particular error is corrected in the errata. See the [RFC Editor](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=4632) for the details.

> Errata ID: 3485
>   **Status: Verified**
>   **Type: Technical**
>
> Reported By: Markus Falb
>   Date Reported: 2013-02-18
>   Verifier Name: RonBonica
>   Date Verified: 2013-02-18
>
> Section 2 says:
>
> ```
> three classes of networks: Class A  
> (most significant address bits '00'), with 128 possible networks each  
> and 16777216 end systems
> ```
>
> <
>   It should say:
>
> ```
> three classes of networks: Class A  
> (most significant address bit '0'), with 128 possible networks each  
> and 16777216 end systems
> ```
>
> <
>   Notes:
>
> MSB bits ’00’ would mean that only 6 bits are available for the
>   network part and this would mean only 64 CLASS A networks.