# RFC 1918 nonsensical sentence

Tags: ipv4, rfc

I am doing an intern and now under a training. The instructor suggested us of reading the RFCs involved with the topics covered in class.

In RFC 1918, they say "An enterprise that decides to use IP addresses out of the address defined in this document can do so without any coordination with IANA or an Internet registry" under the section '3. Private Address Space' as in the picture below.

I presume by "the address defined in this document" they mean Private Address Space.

Or is my understanding incorrect?

[image]

Comment: "out of the address space" means "from the address space", otherwise it would read "outside of the address space". That is also clear when you read the entire text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RFCs often have mistakes or typos, and if one does, there is the Errata. You should always look at any errata that exist for an RFC.

[RFC 1918 Errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/rfc1918) explains:

> RFC 1918, "Address Allocation for Private Internets", February 1996
> [Source of RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/source/): cidrd ()
>
> Errata ID: [1419](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid1419)
> **Status: Held for Document Update**
> **Type: Editorial**
> **Publication Format(s) : TEXT**
> Reported By: Jack Parker
> Date Reported: 2008-05-07
> Held for Document Update by: Pete Resnick
>
> Section 3 says:
>
> ```
> An enterprise that decides to use IP addresses out of the address
> space defined in this document can do so without any coordination
> with IANA or an Internet registry.
> ```
>
> It should say:
>
> ```
> An enterprise that decides to use IP addresses within the address 
> space defined in this document can do so without any coordination 
> with IANA or an Internet registry.
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> There appears to be a slight difference in interpretation with the
> existing phrase, "out of the address space." This 'could' be
> interpreted to mean "outside of the address space," hence changing the
> meaning of the entire statement, if the section's context is not
> considered. In the interest of clarification, would it be possible to
> rephrase this particular section to "within the address space?" I'm
> aware of one case in particular where attorneys argued over this issue
> ad nauseum, regardless of the network architects attempting to
> intervene.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to search for an errata. I will try hard to ask a more elaborated question.

Comment: There is an Errata link at the top of the RFC.

Comment: One would think the actual RFC would have been updated...

Comment: @Charlieface, that does not seem to be the way the RFCs work. See [this question and answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/50014/8499) for one that is particularly bad.